# Postgres update from left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, sql-update

I'm new in PostgreSQL and trying to convert a query from SQL Server.

I have a table Users with, among others, the columns bUsrActive, bUsrAdmin and sUsrClientCode. I want to update Users and set bUsrActive = false if there does not exist a another user with the same sUsrClientCode where bUsrAdmin = true and bUsrActive = true.

In SQL Server I have this query

```
UPDATE u SET u.bUsrActive = 0
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Users u2 ON u.sUsrClientCode = u2.sUsrClientCode AND u2.bUsrAdmin = 1 AND u2.bUsrActive = 1
WHERE u.bUsrAdmin = 0 AND u.bUsrActive = 1 AND u2.nkUsr IS NULL
```

I'm trying to convert this to postgres. I wrote 3 approaches.

1) My first attempt. Obviously not working.

```
UPDATE Users u
    SET bUsrActive = false
FROM Users u2
WHERE u.sUsrClientCode = u2.sUsrClientCode AND u2.bUsrAdmin = true AND u2.bUsrActive = true
AND u.bUsrAdmin = false AND u.bUsrActive = true AND u2.nkUsr IS NULL;
```

2) I understand why it's not working (it updates all users). I just can't figure out how can I reference table Users u in the UPDATE ... SET part.

```
UPDATE Users
    SET bUsrActive = false
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Users u2 ON u.sUsrClientCode = u2.sUsrClientCode AND u2.bUsrAdmin = true AND u2.bUsrActive = true
WHERE u.bUsrAdmin = false AND u.bUsrActive = true AND u2.nkUsr IS NULL;
```

3) The following is working, but not using join.

```
UPDATE Users
    SET bUsrActive = false
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Users u
    WHERE u.sUsrClientCode = Users.sUsrClientCode AND u.bUsrAdmin = true AND u.bUsrActive = true
) AND Users.bUsrAdmin = false AND Users.bUsrActive = true;
```

I'll probably go with the last solution. I just wanted to know if it's possible to do what I want using a left join.

Comment: What's wrong with the third one?

Comment: Nothing, it's working. Just wondering if I can do it the other way using joins. Seems nicer to the eye! I guess the performance would be the same.

Comment: The second one should work (at first sight) what is the error you get?. Are you aware that the semantics of the `FROM` clause is different in PostgreSQL compared to SQL Server?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I'm new and learning now. The second one will update all the records in Users table, not just the "Users u".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here's a generic way to transform this update query from SQL-server form to PostgreSQL:

```
UPDATE Users
 SET bUsrActive = false
WHERE
 ctid IN (
   SELECT u.ctid FROM Users u
      LEFT JOIN Users u2 ON u.sUsrClientCode = u2.sUsrClientCode AND u2.bUsrAdmin = 1 AND u2.bUsrActive = 1
    WHERE u.bUsrAdmin = 0 AND u.bUsrActive = 1 AND u2.nkUsr IS NULL
)
```

[ctid](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html) is a pseudo-column that points to the unique location of a row. You could use instead the primary key of the table if it had one.

The query #2 from the question doesn't do what you expect because the updated table `Users` is never joined to the same table `Users u` in the FROM clause. Just as when you put a table name twice in a FROM clause, they don't get implicitly joined or bound together, they are considered as two independant sets of rows.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It seems that what I'm asking cannot be done. I mean in case of query #2 there is not a way to reference u table somehow. Anyway I'll have in mind your solution for future reference and possible more complex queries. For now I'll go with the 3rd query.

Comment: superb! but cant it be done without subquery at all ?

Answer (score 30):

I think this is the correct way of doing 2) I belive it's more optimal/efficient than doing a sub select.

```
UPDATE Users uOrig
    SET bUsrActive = false
FROM Users u
      LEFT JOIN Users u2 ON u.sUsrClientCode = u2.sUsrClientCode AND u2.bUsrAdmin = 1 AND u2.bUsrActive = 1
WHERE u.bUsrAdmin = 0 AND u.bUsrActive = 1 AND u2.nkUsr IS NULL
    and uOrig.sUsrClientCode = u.sUsrClientCode;
```

Comment: I don't have Postgres installed anymore and it's been 2 years since I last used it, but I believe your query is not syntactical correct. Otherwise my first query would work as well. If I remember correct, in Postgres you can't alias the table you are updating.

Comment: you can alias the table you are updating. You cannot use that alias in the SET clause.

Comment: tested against 9.5 and it works as expected, it make a lot of sense and is faster than a subquery. up.