# Postgres - updates with join gives wrong results

Tags: postgresql, join, where-clause

I'm having some hard time understanding what I'm doing wrong.
The result of this *query* shows the same results for each row instead of being updated by the right result.

### My DATA

I'm trying to update a table of stats over a set of business

```
business_stats ( id SERIAL,
                 pk integer not null,
                 b_total integer,
                 PRIMARY KEY(pk)
                );
```

the details of each business are stored here

```
business_details (id SERIAL,
                  category CHARACTER VARYING,
                  feature_a CHARACTER VARYING,
                  feature_b CHARACTER VARYING,
                  feature_c CHARACTER VARYING
                  );
```

and here a table that associate the *pk* with the *category*

```
datasets (id SERIAL,
          pk integer not null,
          category CHARACTER VARYING;
          PRIMARY KEY(pk)
          );
```

### WHAT I DID (wrong)

```
UPDATE business_stats
SET b_total = agg.total
FROM business_stats b,
     (  SELECT  d.pk, count(bd.id) total
        FROM business_details AS bd
            INNER JOIN datasets AS d
            ON bd.category = d.category
        GROUP BY d.pk
     ) agg
WHERE b.pk = agg.pk;
```

The result of this query is

```
 | id | pk |  b_total  |
 +----+----+-----------+
 |  1 | 14 |  273611   |
 |  2 | 15 |  273611   |
 |  3 | 16 |  273611   |
 |  4 | 17 |  273611   |
```

but if I run just the SELECT the results of each *pk* are completely different

```
 | pk |  agg.total  |
 +----+-------------+
 | 14 |    273611   |
 | 15 |    407802   |
 | 16 |    179996   |
 | 17 |    815580   |
```

### THE QUESTION

- why is this happening?
- why is the WHERE clause not working?

Before writing this question I've used as reference these posts: [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468006/sql-server-update-with-inner-join), [b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498143/postgres-update-from-left-join), [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31962390/postgres-update-with-join)

Comment: Does `business_details` and `datasets` have the same distinct categories?

Comment: Add some foreign key , at least for readability. BTW: Why do your tables have both a (serial) id and an int field defined as Primary Key? And why doesn't `business_details` have a primary key?

Comment: yes, in my case the categories are A, B, C, and D where in table `datasets'  *pk* 14 and *category* is A, *pk* 15 and *category* is B and so on.

Comment: The WHERE clause is working, but there is an implicit self-join with `business_stats`. Try removing `business_stats b,` from FROM clause and changing the WHERE to `business_stats.pk = agg.pk`. But this isn't tested as I could not be bothered to generate data for test tables.

Comment: @wildpasser I know, when I started working on this project I didn't have any clue on how to deal with tables. Now I'm trying to renew all old tables including a pk where is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following (I always recommend against joins in Updates)

```
UPDATE business_stats bs
SET b_total =
(  SELECT   count(c.id) total
        FROM business_details AS bd
        INNER JOIN datasets AS d
        ON bd.category = d.category
       where d.pk=bs.pk
 )
/*optional*/
where exists (SELECT  *
    FROM business_details AS bd
        INNER JOIN datasets AS d
        ON bd.category = d.category
   where d.pk=bs.pk)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your FROM clause. The repeated reference to `business_stats` means you aren't restricting the join like you expect to. You're joining `agg` against the second unrelated mention of `business_stats` rather than the row you want to update.

Something like this is what you are after (*warning* not tested):

```
UPDATE business_stats AS b
SET b_total = agg.total
FROM
     (...) agg
WHERE b.pk = agg.pk;
```

Comment: It is true, the repeated presence of the busines_stats in the FROM make the query get crazy. I've restructured in the same way you show and it works fine. thank you